# Array of numbers which sum can generate each numbers from the set [1, 80]?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, number-systems

I have used Linux Permissions system table which uses 4 numbers, 0, 1, 2, 4
By summing up these 4 numbers you can get permissions for Users, Groups and Other(UGO). It can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 for Users, for Groups and Other

For example UGO=755 equals to this table:

```
   7 5 5
r: 1 1 1
w: 2 0 0
x: 4 4 4
```

r - read permission,

w - write permission,

x - execute permission,

UGO = 755 tells me, Users have rwx permissions, Group and Others have only read and write permissions.

I like this maths stuff as i can ease my work in generating data report. The problem is, I have 80 columns and 18000 rows. In each of the 80 columns I can add single value from the set [1, 80]. To save me some time and prevent, creating many helper tables, I want to sum up all the values in these 80 columns into one single number. But at any time I want to be able to decode this single number into the chosen values from the set [1, 80].

Which numbers would follow next? For example i know, next would be 7, so:
0, 1, 2, 4, 7 gives me the sums in the set [0, 13].

Does this sort of things has some name in maths?

How can I determine the next numbers?

Comment: Are you looking for binary numbers?

Comment: No, decimal? Cannot use binary.

Comment: Why can you not use binary? It seems like the scheme you are describing is exactly what binary does (and given that its linux based, I'd bet it is really just binary). Do you at least know what binary is?

Comment: Why should "*next would be 7*" be true?  Why not $0,1,2,4,8$?  There would be two different ways to write $7$ if you allowed the next row to refer to $7$., either as $[1,~2,~4,~0]$ or as $[0,~0,~0,~7]$

Comment: I know what is binary system of numbers. And the main purpose is to pack several(maybe all 80 natural numbers) numbers into one. But at any time I should be able to decode it to those numbers

Comment: Yup, 8 would do nicely. [0, 15]

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand what you want. It sounds like you should represent a row as a number in base 80, with each digit of the number corresponding to the entry in the corresponding column of that row.

Comment: Well, technically the number/index of the column is not important. I just want to pack for example 43, 54, 37, 78, any combination of 80 numbers each of those numbers can be between 1 and 80(no duplicates allowed), into one number. From the example above, number 755 tells me that User has all the permissions, Group and Others have read and execute permissions

Comment: Would It be all sums from all the numbers in the set [0, 80]? Will all the sums be different numbers? :)

Comment: Are you saying you got 80 permissions?

Comment: No, man, those are not permissions, those are separate values, choices(call them whatever you want) in a document.

Comment: So you still have 3 permissions rwx? Could you give as a small example of what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean you have a set of $80$ permissions and you want a way to encode any subset of permissions formed from this $80$ permissions?

Comment: It sounds like the eighty columns in one row could contain any of the $80^{80}$ different $80$-tuples of values from the set $[1,80].$ If that is so, then encoding these as a single number "to save time" seems like a really, really bad idea. If that is not so, I have no idea what problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: @achillehui yes

Comment: @DavidK Technically its combinations of 80 elements. Wait, let me think a bit...Would sums of each of the 80 combinations of the first 80 natural numbers would give all different summations? :) Gonna write some code.

Comment: @DavidK Something like sums of combinations of 80 elements, k = 1, and then sums of combinations of 80 elements, k = 2 etc... sums of combinations of 80 elements k = 80, given that n!/(k!(n-k)!)

Comment: "In each of the 80 columns I can add single value from the set [1, 80]" suggests that the first five columns could be $34,29, 34,1,66,$ for example. (The meaning of "add" is unclear.) Your response to achillehui, however, implies that there are actually only two possible values in each column. Are the $80$ columns in one row are supposed to specify a _subset_ of the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,80\}$?

Comment: @DavidK Yes. The writer of the document/table decided that in one row all those 80 columns can be blank or can contain any combination(subset) of the numbers between [1, 80], 1, 80 inclusive(no duplicates allowed). Stupid table design, but what can i do.

Comment: @DavidK Unless I create separate table with 80 columns, and search the main table. Anytime I see number from 1 to 80 in these 80 columns from the main table I put 1 in the appropriate column in the helper table . And then I use a SELECT query with Sum function on the helper table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $1,2,4,8,16,32,64$ to add up to all numbers from $0$ to $127$.  As mentioned in the comments, these are the first powers of $2$.  It works because the sum of all the powers of $2$ up to $2^n$ is $2^{n+1}-1$ so the next number you need is $2^{n+1}$.  You need at least $7$ numbers in the set to get more than $64$ choices.  If you make the late numbers smaller, you can reduce the maximum sum.  Making it $27$ will make the maximum sum $80$, but you will have multiple ways to reach certain sums.